# C# - SQLite throwing "database is not open" error when adding table

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm writing an application using C# and System.Data.SQLite (the library from https://system.data.sqlite.org) and I feel like I'm beating my head against a wall. My unit tests on my larger chunks of code are randomly throwing exceptions, so in preparation for asking a question here, I started a new project with as small a chunk of code as I can. This chunk of code, which creates a new `sqlite` file and then adds a table to it, keeps throwing a `Database is not open` error whenever it attempts to add the table.

Looking at the similar questions on Stack Overflow, many of them are regarding using SQLite with Android, which is not the case here.

In my research, I've seen that I want to keep the connection open only for as long as I need it, but as you can see from the code sample, I'm using `using` to isolate the connection and command right next to each other, but I'm still having problems.

There's probably something obvious I'm doing wrong, but I'm at a loss to figure out what it is.

Thanks!

```
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace SmallCode {
    class Program {
        private const string DB_NAME = "Test.sqlite";
        private const string DB_CONN_STRING = "Data Source=" + DB_NAME + ";Version=3;";

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Program p = new Program();
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(DB_NAME);

            using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(DB_CONN_STRING)) {
                string sqlCreateTableAccount = "CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT NOT NULL);";
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlCreateTableAccount, c)) {
                    // EXCEPTION THROWN ON NEXT LINE
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to `.Open` the connection...

```
using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(DB_CONN_STRING)) {
    c.Open();  //<------ ADD THIS LINE
    string sqlCreateTableAccount = "CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT NOT NULL);";
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlCreateTableAccount, c)) {
        // EXCEPTION THROWN ON NEXT LINE
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
 }
```

Creating the connection with `using` doesn't automatically open the connection, it just creates it. You don't need to explicitly `.Close()` it at the end though, it will be closed when the using disposes it.

Comment: Honestly I feel like an idiot, although I don't remember seeing `.Open` in any of the code samples I've seen. Thanks!